# Clean data in excel that comes in varying formats

Tags: excel, data-cleaning, data-conversion

I have an excel table that contain values in these formats. The tables span over 30000 entries.
I need to clean this data so that only the numbers directly after V- are left. This would mean that when the value is SV-51140r3_rule, V-4407..., I would only want 4407 to remain and when the value is SV-245744r822811_rule, I would only want 245744 to remain. I have about 10 formulas that can handle these variations, but it requires a lot of manual labor. I've also used the text to column feature of excel to clean this data as well, but it takes about 30 minutes to an hour to go through the whole document. I'm looking for ways that I can streamline this process so that one formula or function can handle all of these different variations. I'm open to using VBA but don't have a whole lot of experience with it and I am unable to use Pandas or any IDE or programming language. Help please!!

[image]

I've used text to columns to clean data that way and I've used a variation of this formula

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(A631,LEN(A631)-FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A631,"-","#",LEN(A631)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A631,"-",""))))),A631)
```

Comment: Ariel what is your excel version? It is not clear from the picture the pattern of your data, what are the delimiters at the end (space, underscore)? Thanks, Please provide more details about the input and expected output. Please try to provide it in markdown table format. Check this: [Table Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Excel, either of these should work. If you have the ability to use the `Let` function, it will improve your performance, [as this outstanding article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-much-benefit-does-excels-new-let-function-offer-steven-rider/) articulates.

If you're on a really old version of excel, you'll need to hit ctl shift enter to make array formula work.

While these look daunting, all these functions are doing is finding the last `V` (by this function) `=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"","")` and then looping through each character and only returning numbers.

Obviously the mushroom  could be any character that one would consider improbable to appear in the actual data.

### Old School

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"",""),
FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"","")),9^9),
FILTER(COLUMN($1:$1),COLUMN($1:$1)<=LEN(MID(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"",""),
FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"","")),9^9))),1)+0),
MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"",""),
FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"","")),9^9),
FILTER(COLUMN($1:$1),COLUMN($1:$1)<=LEN(MID(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"",""),
FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"","")),9^9))),1),""))
```

### Let Function

(use this if you can)

```
=LET(zText,SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"V",REPT("",999)),999),"",""),
TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(MID(zText,FIND("-",zText),9^9),
FILTER(COLUMN($1:$1),COLUMN($1:$1)<=LEN(MID(zText,FIND("-",zText),9^9))),1)+0),
MID(MID(zText,FIND("-",zText),9^9),
FILTER(COLUMN($1:$1),COLUMN($1:$1)<=LEN(MID(zText,FIND("-",zText),9^9))),1),"")))
```

[image]

### VBA Custom Function

You could also use a VBA custom function to accomplish what you want.

```
Function getNumbersAfterCharcter(aCell As Range, aCharacter As String) As String
    Const errorValue = "#NoValuesInText"
    Dim i As Long, theValue As String
    
        For i = Len(aCell.Value) To 1 Step -1
            theValue = Mid(aCell.Value, i, 1)
            If IsNumeric(theValue) Then
                getNumbersAfterCharcter = Mid(aCell.Value, i, 1) & getNumbersAfterCharcter
            ElseIf theValue = aCharacter Then
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    If getNumbersAfterCharcter = "" Then getNumbersAfterCharcter = errorValue
End Function
```

Comment: The only problem with that is sometimes the V-#### is in the very front, sometimes it's in the middle, and sometimes it's at the end.

Comment: The answer(s) I provided addresses the conditions you represented (see row 5 in screen shot) which means the appropriate response from you would be to either `accept` the answer or point out how my answer didn't address your original question. If you failed to include some conditions in your question, I would recommend reposting a new question that is more clear.